# How to show $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\log\left(\frac{n}i\right)= \Theta(n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

**Is the sum from i=1 to n for log(n/i) = Θ(n)?**

Im studying for a test and appreciate your help.
This is what I did: and got something else

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log(n/i)=\sum_{i=1}^n[\log n-\log i]=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\log n\right)-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \log i\right)=n\log n-\log n!=\log\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right) $$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did it all by yourself, really: 

[Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) shows that  $n^n/n!\sim(2\pi n)^{-1/2}\mathrm e^{n}$, hence $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\log(n/i)=\log(n^n/n!)$ (your post) and
$$\log\left(n^n/n!\right)=n-\frac12\log(2\pi n)+o(1)=n+o(n)=\Theta(n).$$

---

**Edit** (without Stirling's formula)

Call $x_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\log(n/i)=n\log(n)-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\log(i)$, hence $$
x_{n+1}-x_n=(n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log(n)-\log(n+1)=n\log(1+1/n).
$$
Since $\log(1+u)=u+o(u)$ when $u\to0$, $x_{n+1}-x_n=1+o(1)$ when $n\to\infty$. This implies that $x_n=n+o(n)=\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Thank you!! but what is Stirling's formula?? is there another way??

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Checked the link. We didn't learn this formula so i guess there should be easier way to solve it.

Comment: Nusha, see edit.

Comment: Why do we consider $x_{n+1} - x_{n}$ is that similar to the ratio test?

Comment: @bigfocalchord "Why do we consider" Because it works. "is that similar to the ratio test?" Not sure what you mean, please be more precise.

Comment: @Did As in, what is the motivation of considering $x_{n+1}-x_{n}$ and I am wondering if it is similar to the ratio test (for series) where we consider $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ where we consider the behaviour when $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \log i = \int_1^n \log x ~dx + O(1).
$$

Since $\int_1^n \log x~dx = n \log n - n + o(1)$, this shows that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \log (n/i) = n + O(1) = \Theta(n).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't understand..do i get here 1/n?anyway what is wrong with my way? why i dont get the right result?

Comment: @Nusha: Why do you want to get a $1/n$ factor? Do you know what $\Theta(n)$ means? Finally, your way doesn't get a wrong result, you just *haven't got a result* with your way.

Comment: @Nusha: To find $\int_1^n \log x \;dx$, integrate by parts.  If $u = \log x$ then you have $\int u\;dx = ux - \int x\;du$ etc.

Comment: right so i get ( correct me if im wrong) n(logn-1) and thats still give me Θ(nlogn). So is that false?

Comment: @Nusha: I have edited my post, and this should answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

What's your $Θ(n)$ function?

$\sum _{i=1}^n Log\left(\frac{n}{i}\right)=\log \left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)$

Comment: from that i gets Θ(nlogn)

Comment: @Nusha: That's incorrect. How did you get that?